# Error: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string but Locally Doesnt

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

I had an error while building my react app test environment but in locally I build it successfully.

**An error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string**

In my local versions are; Node: 13.14.0, NPM: 6.14.4
Test environment versions are; Node: 12.22.12, NPM: 6.14.16

React:17.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's related to this error https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_sass/issues/3347384.
As the comments says need to downgrade sass to sass@1.58.3

Comment: I tried but didnt changed

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save-dev sass@1.58.3 without "^" solved my issue